# How to predict an image using .pkl file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

I have trained an image classification model and saved it in .pkl file.
Now i don't know how to use that pickle file for single or multiple image prediction.
I have done this for tabular data prediction but not for image

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

classifer = joblib.load("model.pkl")
```

what to do next the method used for predicting tabular data is not working for image.

Comment: What exactly did you save in the pickle file? You should just load it and recover the classifier object, please provide details on this.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have trained it using `fastai library` which uses an `export() function` to save the model in `.pkl` format, but now the problem is for some reason i am not allowed to use `fastai` library in project, but the model that i trained using `fastai` performs really good on my dataset, so yeah i just want to get the prediction out of the `.pkl file` without using `fastai`

Answer (score 0):

it should be the same, you read the image with whatever image module you're using, for example opencv:

```
import cv2 
img = cv2.imread('path/to/img')
classifier.predict(img)
```

if this doesn't work, maybe paste the error so it is easier to provide you with an answer

Comment: not working,and this `predict` is from where sklearn or keras,  my error is `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'predict'` after doing what you suggested

Comment: can you do `print(classifier)` after you load it with joblib to show the parameters? it shouldn't be an `int` object..
This said, if the model is dumpled and loaded properly, if you did some pre-processing to the images you used for training, you should do the same for the images you're using for prediction before predicting them.